# Add a delay method to WinForm application

Tags: winforms, arduino, delay

I'm using a WinForm app to communicate with a micro processor (Arduino Micro). The MCU's serial port requires a few seconds to become available after calling a 'serialPort1.Open();'. So I need to add some kind of delay of perhaps 2 or 3 seconds before attempting to read from the serial port. In addition, I am sending and receiving commands to the MCU during which time I also require a 100ms delay between serial writes and reads.

I've tried using Thread.Sleep (which of course locks up the form) and various timer methods with no luck. I'd be using this delay often so I'd like to have a method that looks something like this:

Anywhere in my form: invokeTimer(2000); // call a delay method with time in ms

```
private void invokeDelay(int time)
{
    // delay here and do nothing for specified time in milliseconds
}
```

Simple examples:

```
serialPort1.Open(); // connect to MCU
invokeDelay(3000);  // give MCU time to make serial stream available

// serial stream should now be available so ...

serialPort1.WriteLine("?");  // ask MCU to provide a response
invokeDelay(100);   // 10-100ms depending on baud rate of MCU to respond
string response = serialPort1.ReadLine();
```

**Alternatively**, I'd be happy with any way of checking if there is serial data available and in this way avoid delays/timers all together. In the Arduino IDE there is a Serial.Available() function, but I don't see anything similar to this in Visual Studio. Otherwise I'd sit in a while loop until a serial stream became available.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: According to the design above all serial port manipulation (Open/Read/Write) can be implemented in additional thread, but not on the main. So the main (GUI) thread will still run.

Comment: **1.** The Serialport.Open() method waits until the port is opened or an exception is thrown. Therefore no need to make some pause after calling the Open(). **2.** Serialport.Write method has timeout that can be changed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Just use the Timer component from the toolbox.  Set its Interval property to 3000 and call its Start() method when you open the port.  In the handler for its Tick event call WriteLine().  You probably want to keep sending ? so just change its Interval to a lower value.